# Add the same parameter twice and execute query

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Dim b as integer = 1
cmd = New SqlCommand
                With cmd
                    .Connection = connecti
                    .CommandTimeout = 0
                    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO HEZDDD(ID,Number,Dates) VALUES (@Id,@Number,@Dates)"
                   With .Parameters
                        .AddWithValue("@ID", NextId())
                        .AddWithValue("@Dates", date.now)

                     If b = 1 Then
                        .AddWithValue("@Number", 1)
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                     End if

                     If b>10 Then
                        .AddWithValue("@Number", 2)
                         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                     End if
                  End With
              End With
```

Looking forward to execute the same query twice using different parameters. The output of this simple query should be two rows.

This is simple example i didnt want to put entire code with around 25 parameters.

Comment: Why not make a Method that takes in the `SqlParameter` as a parameter and call it each time you need to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `Parameters.Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)` to add parameters without values.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
```

Before you execute the command, provide the values for the parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = NextId();
```

Actually, it's always better to use `Parameters.Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType)`, even if you want to set the value immediately. If you use `AddWithValue`, the db type of the parameter has to be inferred from the value. It usually works well, but you might have some surprises. And because `Add` returns the added parameter, you can assign the value in the same line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = NextId();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's already in the parameter collection, you just need to change the value on it on the *second* one.

```
.Parameters("@Number").Value = 2
```

Or out of the with..

```
cmd.Parameters("@Number").Value = 2
```

Comment: {"The variable name '@Number' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."}